# How to read a .xyz file into an array of doubles?

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am new to C, coming from Python. I want to read a .xyz file into a dynamically sized array, to use for various calculations later on in the program. The file is formatted as follows:

```
Title  
Comment    
Symbol 0.000 0.000 0.000  
Symbol 0.000 0.000 0.000  
....
```

The two first lines are not needed, and should just be skipped. The "Symbol" part of the file are chemical symbols--e.g. H, Au, C, Mn--as the .xyz file format is used for storing 3D coordinates of atoms. They need to be ignored as well. I'm interested in the space separated decimal numbers. I therefore want to:

- Skip the first two lines, or just ignore them in some way.
- Skip the first part of each line until the first space.
- Store the three columns of numbers (coordinates) in an array.

So far I have been able to open a file for reading, and then I've attempted to check how long the file is, in order to have the size of the array change depending on how many coordinate sets needs to be stored.

```
// Variable declaration
FILE *fp;
long file_size;

// Open file and error checking
fp = fopen ("file_name" , "r");
if(!fp) perror("file_name"), exit(1);

// Check file size
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

// Close file
fclose(fp);
```

I've been able to skip the first two lines using `fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]")`, to skip to the end of the line. But, I haven't been able to figure out how to loop through the rest of the file, while storing only the decimal numbers in an array.

If I understand correctly, I need to allocate memory for the array, using something like `malloc()` in combination with my `file_size` and then copy the data into the array using `fread()`.

Here is an example of the contents of an actual .xyz file:

```
10 atom system
Energy: -914941.6614699
Ag 0.96834 1.51757 0.02281
Ag 0.96758 -1.51824 -0.02206
Ag -1.80329 2.27401 0.03179
Ag -3.58033 0.00046 0.00126
Ag -1.80447 -2.27338 -0.03537
Ag -0.96581 0.02246 -1.51755
Ag -0.96929 -0.02231 1.51463
Ag 1.80613 0.03321 -2.27213
Ag 3.58027 0.00028 0.00206
Ag 1.80086 -0.03407 2.27455
```

Comment: Use `fgets` to read line by line

Comment: That thing with `fseek` and `ftell` will give you the file size in *bytes*, which tells you almost nothing about how many lines and therefore how many coordinate triples you'll have to read.  (You might be able to use it as an *estimate* of how many lines there'll be, by dividing by some average line length you've managed to determine, but since you're going to have to master the dynamically-allocate-and-grow-if-necessary thing anyway, I'd recommend skipping the filesize determination for now.)

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]")` is an unnecessarily cumbersome, difficult, and error-prone way to read lines from a file.  Just use `fgets`.

Comment: Having read a line using `fgets`, one way of splitting it up into the chemical name and three coordinates would be `sscanf`.

Comment: If you want to allocate the correct amount of memory (without using `realloc`), you need to count the lines in the file (and subtract 2). You can use `fgets` to do that. Then allocate the memory, `rewind` the file, and read each line with `fgets`. Extract the xyz coordinates from each line with `sscanf`.

Comment: Once you have your preliminary version working, you should go back and rewrite the code that blindly skips over the first two lines.  You should have it inspect the first two lines, and complain if they're not as expected.  Sooner or later, someone's going to run your program on the wrong kind of file, and if it blindly reads along (without noticing that the format is wrong), this can lead to mysterious failures.

Comment: Does the first line _always_ contain the number of atoms?  You could use that to simplify processing.  If there is some maximum plausible size you might just allocate enough space for the largest possible array.

Comment: No, the first two lines can contain different lines of text and/or numbers (sometimes they are even left blank), depending on who has created the file and how it they have created it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general approach in C for reading a file into an array of cstrings (pointers to cstrings, so the rough equivalent of a Python list of strings).

```
    int count = 0;                  // line counter;
    int char_count = 0;             // char counter;
    int max_len = 0;                // for storing the longest line length
    int c;                          // for measuring each line length 
    char **str_ptr_arr;             // array of pointers to c-string    

    //extract characters from the file, looking for endlines; note that 
    //the EOF check has to come AFTER the getc(fp) to work properly
    for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {  //edit see comments
        char_count += 1;
        if (c == '\n') {                     //safe comparison see comments
            count += 1;
            if (max_len < char_count) {
                max_len = char_count;      //gets longest line
            }
            char_count = 0;
        }
    }
    //should probably do an feof check here
    rewind(fp);
```

So now you have the number of lines and the length of the longest line, (You can try using the above loop to exclude lines if you want but it might just be easier to read the whole thing into an array of c-strings, then process that into an array of doubles). Now allocate the memory for the array of pointers to c-strings and for the c-strings themselves:

```
    //allocate enough memory to hold all the strings in the file, by first
    //allocating the arr of ptrs then a slot for each c-string pointed to:
    str_ptr_arr = malloc(count * sizeof(char*));               //size of pointer
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        str_ptr_arr[i] = malloc ((max_len + 1) * sizeof(char)); // +1 for '\0' terminate
    }
    rewind(fp);    //rewind again;
```

Now, we have a problem, which is how to populate these cstrings (Python is so much easier!). This works, I'm not sure if it's the expert approach, but here we read into a 
temporary buffer then use strcpy to move the contents of the buffer into our allocated array slots:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        char buff[max_len + 1]; //local temporary buffer that can store any line in file  
        fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);     //read the first string to buffer
        strcpy(str_ptr_arr[i], buff);
    }
```

Note: this is a decent point at which to start excluding lines or removing various substrings from lines, as you can make strcpy conditional on the contents of the buffer, by using other cstring methods.  I'm fairly new at this myself, (learning to write C functions for use in Python progams), but this seems to be the correct approach.

It might also be possible to go directly to a dynamically allocated array of floats for storing your numerical data without bothering with the cstring array; that could be done in the last loop above.  You could split the strings at whitespace, exclude the alphabetical parts, and use the cstring function atof to convert to float datatype.

Edit: I should mention all these memory allocations must be manually freed when you are done with them, and this is the approach:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {      // free each allocated cstring space
        free(str_ptr_arr[i]);
    }
    free(str_ptr_arr);                   // free the cstring pointer space
    str_ptr_arr = NULL;
```

Comment: `char c` should be an int for EOF

Comment: Thanks, will a typecast work for the check, as edit, ```(int)(c) != EOF``` ? [cut] It has to be ```char(c)``` to find the endline ```'\n'``` though.

Comment: No. Make it an int

Comment: @neutrino_logic `getc()` returns an `int`, and in C character constants such as `'\n'` have type `int`, but even if that were not the case (as in C++), the expression `c == '\n'` would implicitly promote the right-hand operand.  It is a safe comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Given, for example:

```
#define STORAGE_INCREMENT 128
typedef struct
{
    double x, y, z ;
} sXYZ ;
```

Then:

```
int atom_count = 0 ;
int atom_capacity = STORAGE_INCREMENT ;
sXYZ* atoms = malloc( atom_capacity * sizeof(*atoms) ) ;

// While valid triplet, discard symbol, get x,y,z
while( fscanf( fp, "%*s%lf%lf%lf", &atoms[atom_count].x, 
                                   &atoms[atom_count].y, 
                                   &atoms[atom_count].z ) == 3 )
{
    // Increment count
    atom_count++ ;

    // If capacity exhausted, expand allocation
    if( atom_count == atom_capacity )
    {
        atom_capacity += STORAGE_INCREMENT ;
        sXYZ* bigger = realloc( atoms, atom_capacity * sizeof(*atoms) ) ;
        if( bigger == NULL )
        {
            break ;
        }
        atoms = bigger ;
    }
}
```

This allocates enough space for 128 atoms initially, and if the space is exhausted, it is expanded by a further 128 atoms - indefinitely.  A smaller value can be used if the files typically have fewer atoms to be a little more memory efficient.  This approach saves you having to first count the number of triplets in the file.

Comment: Please look up why `feof` in a while condition is bad on this site

Comment: @EdHeal : TL;DR.  It was unnecessary in any event; refactored it out.

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks; I would not be offended if you chose to fix the typo's for me.  It is code typed not compiled or tested - not so straightforward on a Chromebook!

Comment: @EdHeal : Compiled (not run) the fragment through https://www.onlinegdb.com/ so it is at least syntactically valid now.

Comment: Should you take care of realloc failure?

Comment: @EdHeal : Yes. Done.

Comment: Should the atom_count comparison with capacity be =

Comment: @EdHeal : we'll get there in the end!